# three cubic homogeneous polynomials satisfy a cubic polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra

**Question:** How can we show algebraically that three cubic homogeneous polynomials in two variables satisfy a cubic polynomial of three variables?

More specifically, let $f_1(x_0,x_1),f_2(x_0,x_1),f_3(x_0,x_1)$ be cubic and homogeneous having no common roots. How can we show the existence of a cubic homogeneous $p(z_0,z_1,z_2)$ such that $p(f_1,f_2,f_3)=0$?

I can handle the case where $f_1,f_2,f_3$ are monomials by inpsection, but how about the general case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your polynomials define a non-constant morphism $$f:\mathbb P^1\to \mathbb P^2:(x_0:x_1)\mapsto (f_1(x_0,x_1):f_2(x_0,x_1):f_3(x_0,x_1))$$ Its image is closed  and hence is an algebraic  curve $f(\mathbb P^1)=C\subset\mathbb P^2$ .
Cutting that curve $C$ with a line $az_1+bz_2+cz_3=0$ shows that $C$ has degree $3$.
Thus $C=V(p(z_1,z_2,z_3))$ is the zero locus of some homogeneous third degree polynomial $p$: the one you desired!

Comment: So here is how i interpret your argument: the curve C intersects a generic line at 3 points (counting multiplicities) and this number must be the degree of C by Bezout's theorem. Is that how you think about it?

Comment: Yes${}{}{}{}$ !

Comment: You are welcome, dear Manos!